# hide unmapped properties in mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

I'm using a DTO object to retrieve information from my @RequestBody in spring rest controller and using the same DTO object in json response.
I want to hide some fields completely from response.

I tried the `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)`which return null for unmapped properties but my question is:

Is there a way to completely hide the unmapped properties based on different mapping methods

Example

```
public Class Order {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String otherField;
}

public Class OrderDto {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String otherFieldA
private String otherFieldB;
}

@Mapper
public interface OrderMapper

//..

@Mappings({
  @Mapping(target = "id", source ="id"),
  @Mapping(target = "name", source ="name"),
  @Mapping(target = "otherFieldA", source ="otherField")
  })
@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
OrderDto fieldAOnlyOrderToOrderDtoMapper(Order order);


@Mappings({
  @Mapping(target = "id", source ="id"),
  @Mapping(target = "name", source ="name"),
  @Mapping(target = "otherFieldB", source ="otherField")
  })
@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
OrderDto fieldBOnlyOrderToOrderDtoMapper(Order order);

}
```

1. thus the result of calling the first mapper [

> fieldAOnlyOrderToOrderDtoMapper

will return an ***OrderDto*** object that has no property named (otherFieldB)

2. and the call for the second mapper

> fieldBOnlyOrderToOrderDtoMapper

will return an ***OrderDto*** object that has no field named (otherFiledA)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to ignore specific fields.. That's done like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface OrderMapper

//..

@Mapping(target = "otherFieldA", source ="otherField")
@Mapping(target = "otherFieldB", ignore=true")
OrderDto fieldAOnlyOrderToOrderDtoMapper(Order order);


@Mapping(target = "otherFieldA", ignore=true)
@Mapping(target = "otherFieldB", source ="otherField")
OrderDto fieldBOnlyOrderToOrderDtoMapper(Order order);

}
```

Comment: the `ignoreByDefault` for `BeanValidation` will return the non-mapped fields with a null value which is good, i wonder if there is a way when you call the mapping method to return the object with only mapped fields (as if non-mapped fields are not defined)

Comment: I'm still not sure whether I understand you.. ignoreByDefault does not map fields that are not explicit defined as mappings. Are you saying that MapStruct explicitly sets not mapped fields to null, and that is what you like to avoid? Could you show an example of a MapperImpl that you would like to see?

Comment: Ok.. I think what you mean.. You mean ignore per property.?

Comment: I updated my answer.. You need to remove the `BeanMapping` and just state that you want to ignore specific fields. Also, you don't need to specify mappings that can be mapped by property name. .Finally, you can use the java8 notation (not requiring the `@Mappings`)..

Comment: @Tarek did my answer help you?

Comment: @Sjaak Should ignoring a field cause it to not be part of the response or just set it to null on the response? I am seeing the latter behavior, and I'd like to have the former. That is,  when I ignore fields, I don't want those to show up in the response _at all_. I am attempting to use the same DTO for different mapping strategies, so there are fields on the DTO that I only sometimes want to include. Is this possible?

Comment: @noisiveRevision: ignore is don't map

Comment: @Sjaak Understood. I think I'm asking too much of MapStruct given it isn't marshalling my DTO/response. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @noisiveRevision, you could use an object factory (see mapstruct documentation) to prepare any empty response you desire. Next mapping determines which fields are populated and which not. You can also use ignoreByDefault to disable the automatic name based mapping